# Doubling the matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a matrix `in` of `size mXn`.

I am trying to create a matrix `out` of size `2mX2n` such that
the `out` matrix contains essentially the same elements as the `in` matrix,
except that the values are alternated with zeros.

For example:

```
in = [[ 1,2,3],
       [4,5,6]]

out = [[1,0,2,0,3,0],
       [0,0,0,0,0,0],
       [4,0,5,0,6,0],
       [0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Is there a vectorized way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
```

Your data:

```
a = np.array([[ 1,2,3],
              [4,5,6]])
```

Create an array twice the size along both dimensions:

```
b = np.zeros([x * 2 for x in a.shape], dtype=a.dtype))
```

Assign the value of `a` to each second value of `b`, again in both dimensions:

```
b[::2,::2] = a
```

The result:

```
>>> b
array([[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```